# sqoop export from hdfs to oracle Error

Tags: oracle, hdfs, sqoop

Command used:

```
sqoop export --connect jdbc:oracle:thin:@//xxx:1521/BDWDEV4 --username xxx --password xxx --table TW5T0 --export-dir '/data/raw/oltp/cogen/oraclexport/TW5T0/2015-08-18' -m 8 --input-fields-terminated-by '\001' --lines-terminated-by '\n' --input-escaped-by '\"' --input-optionally-enclosed-by '\"'
```

The destination table has columns with datatype date in oracle but as show in error it is parsing simple date as timestamp

Error:

```
15/09/11 06:07:12 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 0% reduce 0% 15/09/11 06:07:17 INFO mapreduce.Job: Task Id : attempt_1438142065989_99811_m_000000_0, Status : FAILED Error: java.io.IOException: Can't export data, please check failed map task logs
        at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.TextExportMapper.map(TextExportMapper.java:112)
        at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.TextExportMapper.map(TextExportMapper.java:39)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper.run(Mapper.java:145)
        at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.AutoProgressMapper.run(AutoProgressMapper.java:64)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runNewMapper(MapTask.java:764)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:340)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:168)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1594)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:163) Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't parse input data: '2015-08-15'
        at TZ401.__loadFromFields(TZ401.java:792)
        at TZ401.parse(TZ401.java:645)
        at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.TextExportMapper.map(TextExportMapper.java:83)
        ... 10 more Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Timestamp format must be yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss[.fffffffff]
       at java.sql.Timestamp.valueOf(Timestamp.java:202)
        at TZ401.__loadFromFields(TZ401.java:709)
        ... 12 more
```

Answer (score 4):

Instead of changing your data files in Hadoop, you should use the --map-column-java argument in your sqoop export.

If you have for example two `DATE` columns named `DATE_COLUMN_1` and `DATE_COLUMN_2` in your Oracle table, then you can add the following argument to your sqoop command:

```
--map-column-java DATE_COLUMN_1=java.sql.Date,DATE_COLUMN_2=java.sql.Date
```

As mentioned before, the JDBC format has to be used in your Hadoop text file. But in this case `yyyy-mm-dd` will work.

Answer (score 1):

From
http://archive.cloudera.com/cdh/3/sqoop/SqoopUserGuide.html#_dates_and_times,

> Oracle JDBC represents DATE and TIME SQL types as TIMESTAMP values. Any DATE columns in an Oracle database will be imported as a TIMESTAMP in Sqoop, and Sqoop-generated code will store these values in java.sql.Timestamp fields.
>
> When exporting data back to a database, Sqoop parses text fields as
>   TIMESTAMP types (with the form yyyy-mm-dd HH:MM:SS.ffffffff) even if
>   you expect these fields to be formatted with the JDBC date escape
>   format of yyyy-mm-dd. Dates exported to Oracle should be formatted as
>   full timestamps.

So you would need to format the dates in your files to conform to the format  `yyyy-mm-dd HH:MM:SS.ffffffff` before exporting to Oracle.

EDIT:

Answering the comment,

> There around 70 files(tables) in hdfs I need to export..So,in all
>   files I need to change the date from yyyy-mm-dd to yyyy-mm-dd
>   HH:MM:SS.ffffffff, any simple way to format it.

Well you could write an `awk` script to do that for you. Or else you can check if the below idea works:

1. Create a new temporary table `TEMPIMPORT` with the same structure as table `TW5T0` except changing the column which has the `DATE` datatype to `VARCHAR2`
2. Load using Sqoop into the new temporary table `TEMPIMPORT`.
3. Run the DML below to export the data back int `TW5T0` (and commit of course):

   insert into tw5t0 (select   [[all_your_columns_here_except_date_column]],to_date(date_column,'yyyy-mm-dd') from tempimport);

Comment: There around 70 files(tables) in hdfs I need to export..So,in all files I need to change the date from  yyyy-mm-dd to yyyy-mm-dd HH:MM:SS.ffffffff, any simple way to format it.

Comment: @vinayak Updated the answer for the comment.

Answer (score 1):

used --connection-param-file ora.porperties in export sqoop

ora.properties contains
oracle.jdbc.mapDateToTimestamp=false

Answer (score 0):

> Oracle drivers map oracle.sql.DATE to java.sql.Timestamp, retaining
>   the time information.  If you still want the incorrect but 10g
>   compatible oracle.sql.DATE to java.sql.Date mapping, then you can get
>   it by setting the value of mapDateToTimestamp flag to false (default
>   is true).

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/java.112/e16548/apxref.htm#JJDBC28920

For using with sqoop you need to add option:

`--connection-param-file conn-param-file.txt`

conn-param-file.txt:

`oracle.jdbc.mapDateToTimestamp=false`

Answer (score 0):

For using with sqoop you need to add option:

`--connection-param-file conn-param-file.txt`

conn-param-file.txt:

`oracle.jdbc.mapDateToTimestamp=false`

Answer (score 0):

If Hive table columns sequence doesn't match with RDBMS table columns sequence order then there is a chance of same error.
I have resolve my issue after rearrange the columns in RDBMS by creating the table again.