# Sqoop export for varchar into timestamp field in Oracle

Tags: oracle, date, timestamp, export, sqoop

sqoop  export fails when when string YYYYMMDDHHMISS loaded into a timestamp column in Oracle

```
Error: java.io.IOException: Can't export data, please check failed map task logs
    at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.TextExportMapper.map(TextExportMapper.java:112)
    at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.TextExportMapper.map(TextExportMapper.java:39)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper.run(Mapper.java:146)
    at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.AutoProgressMapper.run(AutoProgressMapper.java:64)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runNewMapper(MapTask.java:796)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:346)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:163)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1595)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:158)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't parse input data: '20170908220629'
    at 
    at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.TextExportMapper.map(TextExportMapper.java:83)
    ... 10 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Timestamp format must be yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss[.fffffffff]
    at java.sql.Timestamp.valueOf(Timestamp.java:204)
```

Comment: What is your question? This looks pretty clear that the date format is not expected so the conversion fails. What are you trying to do?

Comment: Oracle doesn't accept other date formats coming from external systems, There are lot same questions on the stack and in other platforms with the same issue, please put some effort into researching. I'm not answering this question as it is duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32537148/sqoop-export-from-hdfs-to-oracle-error Simple solution is to change the format of date you are exporting to "yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss" or change the datatype to string in oracle.